# Using post processing shaders on objects/groups in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, post-processing

I'm trying to add some blur effects via post processing in a WebGL canvas with THREE.js.

The thing is, I need this effects only on selected objects/groups, which contain multiple other things.
For example: I have two rotating objects and want to add a blur effect to one of them (the green one in my example).
I already played a little bit with the MaskPass, but I didn't get it to work with my stuff and I also didn't find an matching example in the THREE.js examples.

Here is an Example with the whole screen blured:

```js
var container;

var camera, scene, renderer, composer;

var cube1, cube2, cube3, cube4;

var group1, group2;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.y = 150;
    camera.position.z = 500;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

   // Cube
   var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
   var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x4444ff } );
   var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
   var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x66ff66 } );
   var material4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

   cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material1 );
   
   cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
   cube2.rotation.x = Math.PI / 3;
   cube2.rotation.y = Math.PI / 3;
   
   cube3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material3 );
   
   cube4 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material4 );
   cube4.rotation.x = Math.PI / 3;
   cube4.rotation.y = Math.PI / 3;
   
   group1 = new THREE.Object3D();
   group1.add(cube1);
   group1.add(cube2);
   group1.position.y = 150;
   group1.position.x = 200;
   
   group2 = new THREE.Object3D();
   group2.add(cube3);
   group2.add(cube4);
   group2.position.y = 150;
   group2.position.x = -200;
   
   scene.add( group1 );
   scene.add( group2 );

   renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
   renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
   
   var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
   var blurShaderPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.HorizontalBlurShader);
   blurShaderPass.uniforms.h.value = 2.5 / 512;
   blurShaderPass.renderToScreen = true;
   
   composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
   composer.addPass(renderPass);
   composer.addPass(blurShaderPass);
}

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 render();
}

function render() {
   group1.rotation.y -= 0.01;
   group2.rotation.y -= 0.15;
   composer.render();
}
```

```css
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/postprocessing/ClearPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="https://webauth.cloud/libs/three/shaders/HorizontalBlurShader.js"></script>
```